# IE7 CSS issue with a ul in a container

Tags: html, css, browser, internet-explorer-7

I'm not that good at debugging IE, because... well because I hate it and want nothing to do with it >_<

Anyway... I'm creating this treeview plugin and everything looks great...

But, ***for some reason***, it looks totally messed up in IE7, and IE7 only (don't know about IE6 etc, but seriously, screw that piece of #%/"#).

[image: looks like this, piece of "%(!¤ IE...].

**Does anyone know how to fix it or why it's behaving this way?**

[Here's the generated html & css example](http://jsfiddle.net/a4hmn/)

---

### CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.vbc-treeview{
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    overflow: auto;

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    border: 1px solid #828790;
    margin: 5px;

}

.vbc-treeview ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.vbc-treeview ul:first-child{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.vbc-treeview li{
    position: relative;
}

.vbc-treeview li:first-child{
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}

.vbc-treeview li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    cursor: default;
    line-height: 16px;
}

.vbc-treeview .tv-sibling{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    background: url(http://img813.imageshack.us/img813/1664/connector.png);
}

.vbc-treeview .tv-sibling-horizontal{
    left: -12px;
    top: 8px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 1px;
    width: 8px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.vbc-treeview .tv-sibling-vertical{
    left: -14px;
    top: 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.vbc-treeview .tv-sibling-first{
    top: 8px;
}

.vbc-treeview .tv-collapse{
    position: absolute;
    background: url(http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/2134/collapser.png) no-repeat center;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    left: -18px;
    top: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.vbc-treeview .tv-expanded{
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.vbc-treeview .tv-collapsed{
    background-position: -10px 0px;
}
```

---

### HTML

```
<div class="tree vbc-treeview">
    <ul>
        <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-vertical tv-sibling-first" style="height: 609px;"></div>
        <li class="tv-expanded">
            <div class="tv-collapse tv-expanded"></div>
            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
            <a href="#">Node 0,2</a>
            <ul>
                <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-vertical" style="height: 41px;"></div>
                <li>
                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                    <a href="#">Node 0,2,0</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                    <a href="#">Node 0,2,1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                    <a href="#">Node 0,2,2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="tv-expanded">
            <div class="tv-collapse tv-expanded"></div>
            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
            <a href="#">Node0</a>
            <ul>
                <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-vertical" style="height: 249px;"></div>
                <li class="tv-expanded">
                    <div class="tv-collapse tv-expanded"></div>
                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                    <a href="#">Node 0,0</a>
                    <ul>
                        <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-vertical" style="height: 121px;"></div>
                        <li>
                            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                            <a href="#">Node 0,0</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                            <a href="#">Node 0,1</a></li>
                        <li class="tv-expanded">
                            <div class="tv-collapse tv-expanded"></div>
                            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                            <a href="#">Node 0,2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-vertical" style="height: 57px;"></div>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                                    <a href="#">Node 0,2,0</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                                    <a href="#">Node 0,2,1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                                    <a href="#">Node 0,2,2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                                    <a href="#">Node 0,2,3</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                            <a href="#">Node 0,3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                    <a href="#">Node 0,1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="tv-expanded">
                    <div class="tv-collapse tv-expanded"></div>
                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                    <a href="#">Node 0,2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-vertical" style="height: 57px;"></div>
                        <li>
                            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                            <a href="#">Node 0,2,0</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                            <a href="#">Node 0,2,1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                            <a href="#">Node 0,2,2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                            <a href="#">Node 0,2,3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                    <a href="#">Node 0,3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="tv-expanded"><div class="tv-collapse tv-expanded"></div><div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
            <a href="#">Node1</a>
            <ul><div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-vertical" style="height: 25px;"></div>
                <li><div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div><a href="#">Node 1,0</a></li>
                <li><div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div><a href="#">Node 1,1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
            <a href="#">Node2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tv-expanded">
            <div class="tv-collapse tv-expanded"></div>
            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
            <a href="#">Node3</a>
            <ul>
                <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-vertical" style="height: 185px;"></div>
                <li>
                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                    <a href="#">Node 3,0</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                    <a href="#">Node 3,1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="tv-expanded">
                    <div class="tv-collapse tv-expanded"></div>
                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                    <a href="#">Node 3,2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-vertical" style="height: 121px;"></div>
                        <li>
                            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                            <a href="#">Node 3,2,0</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="tv-expanded">
                            <div class="tv-collapse tv-expanded"></div>
                            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                            <a href="#">Node 3,2,1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-vertical" style="height: 57px;"></div>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                                    <a href="#">Node 3,2,1,0</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                                    <a href="#">Node 3,2,1,1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                                    <a href="#">Node 3,2,1,2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                                    <a href="#">Node 3,2,1,3</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                            <a href="#">Node 3,2,2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                            <a href="#">Node 3,2,3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
                    <a href="#">Node 3,3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="tv-sibling tv-sibling-horizontal"></div>
            <a href="#">Node4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `position:relative` on the parent `div`.

Comment: That did it it, that fixed it all. In conjunction with the `*{zoom:1;}` suggestion from @rcdmk, it looks like it's supposed to. Thanks! [Here's the result](http://jsfiddle.net/a4hmn/4/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `position: relative;` on the items.

Remove it and it should work.

Also, try adding a `zoom: 1` to these elements to see if it work.

Comment: Hm, that sort of worked. I added a `*{zoom:1;}` and removed the `position:relative` but then the connector graphics aren't being displayed properly, since there is no relative position for them. The page also seem to be bigger than it's supposed to be (vertical scrollbar?). [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4hmn/2/)

Comment: I've said to remove the relative positioning from the items. You removed the relative positioning from the ul aswell. This is causing the problem.